# Enviar datos de formulario oculto

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios

cuando escribo los datos de un usuario en wordpress para registrarse, deseo que al pulsar el botón "Registrar o Enviar" este acceda al sitio, es decir que quede logueado de manera automática. (mediante código ya he logrado activarlo sin necesidad de confirmar por email)

Se me ocurre tener un formulario oculto en el mismo sitio que llene los datos de los inputs con los valores del usuario recién registrado, y acceda de inmediato. Para esto pienso que al pulsar el botón Registrar realice el envío de los dos formularios, uno que registra y otro que loguee al usuario.

entiendo puedo usar inputs ocultos, pero que código puedo usar para que al pulsar el botón Registrar, también se active el botón Login.

de antemano muchas gracias.

```
<input id="prodId" name="prodId" type="hidden" value="xm234jq">
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que utilizas para el registro y la consulta?

Comment: ¿Por que no usas variables de sesion? Inicias sesion al registrar o logear y se queda logueado hasta que cierre la sesion...

Comment: Te estás complicando demasiado para hacer algo que Wordpress puede hacer automáticamente: [Inicio de sesión automático después del registro](https://kb.accessally.com/tutorials/wordpress-auto-login-after-registration/) Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Yo creo que con usar *display: none* en las partes a ocultar ya no deberias tener ningun problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perfecto Javi PS no conocía esa forma
indagando por la web me encontré con esta función propia de Wordpress
y como bien decían los demás compañeros estaba complicandome la vida

[aqui](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) la funcion

wp_signon( array $credentials = array(), string|bool $secure_cookie = '' )

aquí un ejemplo de la misma página, voy a probar ambas.

```
/**
 * Perform automatic login.
 */
function wpdocs_custom_login() {
    $creds = array(
        'user_login'    => 'example',
        'user_password' => 'plaintextpw',
        'remember'      => true
    );

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    }
}

// Run before the headers and cookies are sent.
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_custom_login' );
```